# Robot Framework : How to remove all spaces after the string

Tags: string, robotframework, trim

I am new to robot framework.
I want to know how can i remove all white spaces after the string .
My string is "OTP Hello
"
I want all spaces and line break after Hello to get deleted
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Strip String`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Strip%20String) keyword in the Strings library, and specify `mode=right`, to remove the whitespace only from the right side. Sample:

```
${src}=     Set Variable    OTP Hello${SPACE}\n
Log To Console      The source: ---${src}---
${stripped}=   Strip String    ${src}      mode=right
Log To Console      The result: ---${stripped}---
```

The output will be:

```
The source: ---OTP Hello 
---
The result: ---OTP Hello---
```

Comment: I know, there's no other option for it . Look around in the Strings library, it has other methods that can help you with strings manipulation.